Future continuous vs perfect continuous
I want to show that one action will be already in progress before another one happens. Examples

When we come they will be waiting for us

When we come they will have been waiting for us


Are both fine here or future perfect continuous must be used with some time expression like "for two hours" and without that my #2 sentence is wrong?

not "come" but "arrive". You need the sense of "get there".  But if you want to show that their waiting  commenced before your arrival, and is not merely coincident with it, you must say "will have been waiting". Test if for yourself by adding "for over two hours".

Sentence (2) is much more idiomatic with a time expression.

No, 2) is not wrong in context. But does usually include a time expression.

Future Perfect Continuous Tense use

I want to show that one action will be already in progress before another one happens.

When we use the Future Perfect Continuous Tense, this is possible.
Now looking at your examples

When we come they will be waiting for us.
When we come, they will have been waiting for us.

In both cases the use of the verb 'come' is incorrect as you are not coming but going to somebody's place.
The correct form with come is -
When they come, we will be waiting for them.
If you intend to say you are going to someone's place the correct verb is reach or arrive.

Are both fine here or future perfect continuous must be used with some time expression like "for two hours" and without that my #2 sentence is wrong?

You are correct sentence #2 is wrong without a time expression. So the correct form of the sentences would be

When we arrive there they will be waiting for us. (You had informed them earlier and they came to pick you up)
When we arrive, they will have been waiting for us for two hours. ( Because your flight had been delayed by two hours)

Another example to show the use of Future Perfect Continuous Tense. The flight from New Delhi to London Heathrow Airport is 9 hours. You can say
When we reach Heathrow Airport, we will have been travelling for nine hours.
